# Need to copy Azure blob files from one folder to another folder and create zip

Tags: javascript, c#, azure

I am working on a project.  I have my  files in a blob, and I need to copy these Azure blob files from one folder to another folder.  I also need to create a zip file.

Please someone help me; I am new to this and have no idea what to do.

Comment: It's hard to say if this question isn't too broad. You really should try at least something and present it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is good article on MSDN covering Azure blob containers.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "photo1.jpg".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("photo1.jpg");

// Save blob contents to a file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"path\myfile"))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

You can use ListBlobs method to get all blobs, then iterate through them to download

```
CloudBlobDirectory dir = container.GetDirectoryReference("yourFolder");
var blobs = dir.ListBlobs(new BlobRequestOptions() { UseFlatBlobListing = true });
```

There are lots of 3rd party libraries to work with zip archives, for example https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd

Answer (score 1):

First, you should let us know what language you are working with.  As none is stated, I will assume C#.

I would begin by following the Blob tutorial located here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

I would then install a nugget package for a zip library.  Here are a few good ones with documentation/samples:
http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/ 
https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd

My personal preferred library here is DotNetZip due to ease of use and nice documentation right on the page.

Your high level code will be:

Iterate each container

Collect All Blobs.
Copy All Blobs to new location.
Use the Zip library to zip stuff up.

Below is some sample code to help get you rolling, If you have too many blobs, this may fail on an out of memory exception, however this should work for your scenario.  If you get an out of memory scenario, just do one blob at a time instead of all at once.

```
    string key = "";
    string accountName = "mystorageaccount";
    string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="
                            + accountName + ";AccountKey=" + key;
    var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    //below line not necessary, just for demo how to get a container.
    var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

    List<ICloudBlob> allblobs = new List<ICloudBlob>;
    foreach(CloudBlobContainer container in blobClient.ListContainers())
    {
        allblobs.AddRange((from ICloudBlob blob in
                        container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true)
                        select blob));
    }
```